# How to get Windows Script Host to run in XP SP3?

Tags: windows-xp, script, services, community

OS: Windows XP SP3

AV: Microsoft Security Essentials

Network Environment: Standalone

Invocation of wscript.exe fails.

The error message is as follows -

```
Initialization of the Windows Script Host failed. (The service cannot be started,
either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.
)
```

Resolution attempts so far

Update registry entry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Script Host\Settings

- Changed UseWINSAFER to 0
- Introduced DWORD: Enabled = 1
- Enabled Server Service

UPDATE: 
Downloaded WSH5.7 installable from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8247 only to have it abort with the message that my SP is newer than the setup.

So far these above do not appear to work. The latter part of the message makes me wonder whether is is a windows service/access control issue that needs to be enabled/started for WSH to work.

What should be done to get Windows Host Service to execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after the attempts listed in the question above I had a moment of serendipity. It occurred to me to start *all* services under windows, and then execute the script.

When this worked I started to stop the services which I had started one at a time (as there are many services which are stopped/disabled on my system by default) until the script threw the above error again.

Starting the service ***Machine Debug Manager*** allowed me to move forward from the error mentioned in the question.